# How to convert xpath element which contains text to css

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, cypress

I have the following Xpath to locate an element which has the text Manager.  I need to use CSS in our Cypress IO automation.  My test adds a new item in the Gui by clicking the Add button and types in Manager and clicks the Save button.  I want to do an Assertion the text Manager exists when it has been saved.  the Assertion is not working due to not finding the correct locator.

Xpath locator:

```
//span[contains(text(),'Manager')]
```

I tried to use the following as CSS

```
cy.get('span:contains("Operator")
```

The locator is not working I get the following error when i run my code

```
o   

find.form-control3
o   14assertexpected [ <span.form-control>, 2 more... ] to have text Manager, but the text was ManagerUndefinedManager3
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '[ <span.form-control>, 2 more... ]' to have text 'Manager', but the text was 'UndefinedManager'
```

The first item by default in the list of elements is called Undefined.  When a new entry is added it is Manager in the list.
My code snippet is:

```
static get AudienceTextfieldSavedValue(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
       //return cy.get('span:contains("Manager")').should('have.text', 'Manager');

        //return cy.get('(ul).find(li  with given text)..find(form-control).have "Manager")')
        return cy.get('.cdk-drop-list').find('.form-control').should('have.text', 'Manager');
    }

it('Add Audience', () => {
        Lists.navigateToLists;
        Audience.clickAdd;        
        Audience.AudienceTextfield.type("Manager");        
        Audience.getSaveButton.click().then(() => {                            
            cy.wait(['@savingAudienceRecord']);
        });
        Audience.AudienceTextfieldSavedValue.should('have.text', 'Manager');
  });
```

The HTML snippet is:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the correct css locator I should use please?  Thanks
Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, the simplest reproduction of what happens during the test is

DOM starts with two spans

```html
<ul class="cdk-drop-list">
  <li><span class="form-control">Manager</span></li>
  <li><span class="form-control">Undefined</span></li>
</ul>
```

You add the new entry and the DOM becomes

```html
<ul class="cdk-drop-list">
  <li><span class="form-control">Manager</span></li>
  <li><span class="form-control">Undefined</span></li>
  <li><span class="form-control">Manager</span></li>
</ul>
```

You want to check the last entry, so `AudienceTextfieldSavedValue()` should only select the last span in the list (assuming the save action does not sort the list).

```js
static get AudienceTextfieldSavedValue(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
  return cy.get('.cdk-drop-list').find('.form-control')
    .last()                           // assuming the saved field is the last one
    .should('have.text', 'Manager');
}

it('Add Audience', () => {
  Lists.navigateToLists;
  Audience.clickAdd;        
  Audience.AudienceTextfield.type("Manager");        
  Audience.getSaveButton.click().then(() => {                            
    cy.wait(['@savingAudienceRecord']);
  });
  Audience.AudienceTextfieldSavedValue.should('have.text', 'Manager');
});
```

`.should('have.text', 'Manager')` is performed twice, so you can perhaps remove it from `AudienceTextfieldSavedValue()` and just return the last entry.

That way, you can test with different text entry.

---

You may also want check the number of entries increases from 2 to 3, because if `Audience.getSaveButton.click()` fails to do the save your test would still pass.

```js
static get AudienceTextfieldSavedValue(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
  return cy.get('.cdk-drop-list').find('.form-control')
    .last()                           // assuming the saved field is the last one
}

static get AudienceTextfieldCount(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {
  return cy.get('.cdk-drop-list').find('.form-control')
    .its('length')
}

it('Add Audience', () => {
  Lists.navigateToLists;

  Audience.AudienceTextfieldCount().should('eq', 2)

  Audience.clickAdd;        
  Audience.AudienceTextfield.type("Manager");        
  Audience.getSaveButton.click().then(() => {                            
    cy.wait(['@savingAudienceRecord']);
  });

  Audience.AudienceTextfieldCount().should('eq', 3)
  Audience.AudienceTextfieldSavedValue.should('have.text', 'Manager');
});
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you very much for your help